# Get child data by child id through the aggregate root in DDD and EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, aggregates

For asking my question let me explain a bit about this part of the project:
Very simple blog system with these entities:
`Posts` - `PostsCategories` - `Categories`
Post and Category have Many-to-Many relationships.

```cs
// Post
public Id { get; private set; }
public Title { get; private set; }
public IReadOnlyCollection<PostsCategories> Categories => _categories;
private List<PostsCategories> _categories = new();
```

```cs
// Category
public Id { get; private set; }
public Title { get; private set; }
public IReadOnlyCollection<PostsCategories> Posts => _posts;
private List<PostsCategories> _posts = new();
```

```cs
// PostsCategories (this is Value Object)
public Guid PostId { get; private set; }
public Post Post { get; protected set; }

public Guid CategoryId { get; private set; }
public Category Category { get; protected set; }
```

These 3 entities are in Blog aggregate: `Post` is Aggregate root, `Category` is entity, and `PostsCategories` is ValueObject.
Now as I know (In DDD we should have one repository for each AggregateRoot and other members can not have repository) So I want to get category by id with EF Core.

**This is my question: How can I get single category with its posts with having category Id in the PostsRepository.cs?**

============== **Update** ===============
Is this query correct? (Performance and standards)

```cs
var category = await Entity
.Include(x => x.Categories)
.ThenInclude(x => x.Category)SelectMany(x => x.Categories)
.Select(x => x.Category)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => string.Equals(x.Slug.Value, slug, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: If PostCategoriies does not need to contain anything other than to serve as the joining table, you can simplify your domain where Post has a collection of Categories and Category has a collection of Posts and let EF manage the joining table entirely behind the scenes. This makes dealing with the relationships a lot simpler. The only time you need to worry about the joining entity is if there are additional properties you want to track about the relationship that would sit in the PostCategories table.

Comment: Thank you @StevePy actually, you are totally right, I was working with the old way and I forget that we don't need to create a relation table manually anymore. This helped me so much, simpler queries!

Comment: Another thing that I didn't pay attention, of course, in the future I will need the categories to query all of them, for example for listing all categories in the Manage Categories page, so in this case I can not query those categories that they don't use by any post! So as all of you mentioned, I need a repository for Categoties, but the question is Do I need to change category to Aggregate Root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and reading about this topic, I found out that I had a miss understanding of aggregation, in the case if, I was putting Categories in another aggregate called Blog or Post that Post is an Aggregate root, So how about if I needed to get the list of all categories? with DDD and my implementation, I could not do that! because I can only access to categories that they are assigned to post! This is a sign to transfer the Category entity to another aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

The models that are designed in DDD are usually not a good option for queries, and you should use design or other options for the queries. If your goal is to make changes in the category, aggregate should be loaded and changes should be made from the aggregate side. But if your goal is only to display information, you can create a query repository for the category, which is used only for the query.

Comment: Yeah, dear @Mohsen Farokhi you were so close to my answer, It depends on my design and requirements,

Answer (score 0):

my suggest is do it in CategoryRepository

```
context.Category.Query().Include(category => category.PostsCategory).ThenInclude(postsCategory => postsCategory.Post).FirstOrDeafult(category => category.Id == id)
```

Comment: Dear @Lucas Kruger , thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned I am going to follow DDD standards and in this case I have these 3 entities in one Aggregate called Blog and Post is AggregateRoot so I don't have CategoryRepository, Otherwise, I want to know how to do this kind of query (Think I need this query with this conditions that I wrote)